# Which VM instance is used for Azure App Service Environment (ASE) V1?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-ase

When I select Premium plan in Azure Pricing Calculator, I can see the Instances choice available (P1V3, P2V3, P3V3 etc).

However when I select Isolated or Isolated V2 plan, I could not easily find which instance Isolated Plan are based on.

Where is the instance details for Isolated and Isolated V2 App service plan are documented in Azure App Service pricing detail Docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- App Service Environment V2 supports [Isolated App Service plans (I1, I2, I3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro)

[image]

- App Service Environment V3 supports [Isolated App Service plans (I1V2, I2V2, I3V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/creation)
  [image]

Please refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/overview) and [Isolated Service Plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) for more information.